# Why is there a 'zeta' in zeta converter?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

Why is the **zeta** converter called so? What is the significance of the Greek letter '\$\zeta\$' in it?

Comment: I have no idea what a "Zeta converter" is so include a link to an example, article or include a schematic. Realize that the same name might be used for **2** completely different designs in different fields of EE. So that's why **providing context** is always needed.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the Zeta is about as important as the SEPIC, just lesser known. I think it was published 1989-90 or so. One would have to scourge through patents and papers from that era.

Comment: Do you, Domino, happen to have access to publications that cite the inventors of that topology? that's where I'd start looking

Comment: @MarcusMüller I found a schematic with a simple Google search. It is still OP's task to include that schematic (assuming that's what OP is asking about) or any other reference.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie that's why I asked for references :)

Comment: Zeta = "inverse SEPIC."  I went through a dozen papers and application notes, and no one explains why an "inverse SEPIC" is called "zeta."  They all just assume you know what it is and jump right into implementation details without mentioning where it came from and how it got its name.  I mean, SEPIC (single ended primary inductor) is defined all over the place.  Zeta is like the "Fight Club" of DC-DC converters - the first rule of the zeta converter is "you don't talk about the zeta converter."

Comment: @JRE Doesn't that give us, right here, right now, the freedom to start spreading a definition of our own?

Comment: @JRE "Zero Effort Time Analysis" converter? "Zooms EMI To All frequencies" converter? "Zeta in Effect just Totally yet Another" converter?

Comment: This is an interesting question. The first reference I've been able to find accessible on the internet is a patent from 1990 (https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/5b/7c/64/019ffa659ff835/US4931716.pdf) which mentions "[...] Applying the above rules to six basic converter topologies (buck, boost, buck-boost, Cuk, SEPIC, and Zeta) [...]" suggesting that this term was in common usage before 1990

Comment: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/22/d1/79/34ae3c9d7f59e3/US4841220.pdf shows that it was common before 1987

Comment: No @MarcusMüller, I just came across the topology, while working on my project.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this topology has several names: Zeta, Inverse SEPIC, Dual-SEPIC, so it's a bit confusing.

In **[this video (@10m 45s)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPxQylJGJMA&t=640s)**, professor **Sam Ben-Yaakov** does a brilliant walk-through of how the Zeta converter operates, and takes a sidestep to explain how did it evolve.

He says

> The first time, to my knowledge, that this circuit was called "Zeta" is in this paper [...] in 1994.

And the namesake is

> Zeta, 6th Greek letter, since it is the sixth in the sequence:
>
> Buck, Boost, Buck-Boost, Ćuk, SEPIC, **Dual-SEPIC**

So this topology was called "Zeta" a few years after it was first introduced, or at least not everybody called it Zeta initially. The seminal paper introducing it (~1989?) named it "Dual-SEPIC", because it was SEPIC's "dual" — essentially the same, with 4 components being swapped. But probably that name was disliked as being too confusing, and the Zeta name became the preferred one.

## Details that may be lost to history

While the explanation is quite likely the right one, the timing might be off. The paper he cites does not actually discuss naming or greek letters at all. It may be related somehow, but we'll have to trust the professor on that one — he is old enough to remember when this renaming happened (he was in his forties back then!). As hinted in the comments, there's patent evidence that the Zeta name predates the paper. Maybe both names co-existed for a while, and eventually Zeta become the prevalent one.